# OSX- Putting custom controls on a custom graphic

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, graphics

I'm building a UI for an OSX project. The company that's hiring me wants the main window to be a custom graphic, with custom controls on top of it.  I know how to show a custom graphic, and I know how to show custom buttons with their own bitmaps, but I have not figured out how to put the custom buttons on the custom graphic and have the whole thing work.

Can someone point me to some source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new subclass of NSView called say viewBgrnd. Put the drawing code for your background into the drawRect of your new custom view object. Set the Class of your Window's NSView to this new Custom Class. Add your customised buttons on top.